# Почему combobox не выделяется при нажатии?

Tags: qt, golang, combobox

Такая проблема, что при нажатии на combobox он никак не выделяется. Пробовал создавать отдельно приложение с combobox-ми  все работало нормально и при нажатии происходило выделение combobox-а? Пишу используя биндинги go-qt therecipe.

как должно быть при нажатии на combobox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а так у меня (не видно что на нем фокус, хотя писать и выбирать можно нормально)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
код

```
func setCombobox(vbox *widgets.QVBoxLayout,fields []string)[]widgets.QComboBox{
var inputs []widgets.QComboBox
for i := 0;i < len(fields);i++{
    label := widgets.NewQLabel2(fields[i],nil,0)
    comboBox := widgets.NewQComboBox(nil)
    comboBox.SetEditable(true)
    comboBox.SetEditFocus(true)
    entries,err := jsonConfig.GetCatalogEntries()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    entriesNames := jsonConfig.GetNamesFrom(entries)
    comboBox.AddItems(entriesNames)
    comboBox.SetCurrentText("")
    vbox.AddWidget(label,0,0)
    vbox.AddWidget(comboBox, 0, 0)
    inputs = append(inputs,*comboBox)
}
return inputs
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка возникала из-за того, что в одной из функций случайно была продублирована строка, после её удаления все заработало нормально.

```
widgets.NewQApplication(len(os.Args), os.Args)
```